# C++ Rest SDK getting a value from initial call

Tags: c++11, asynchronous

Have the async code working but don't see how I can use the values return in the main code.  Is this possible?  All the examples I have seen show all logic in the .then continuations.  I don't want to convert all the code to async just the web api call.

```
pplx::task<void> GetXMLAsync() {
    http_client client("url")
    return client.request().then([=](http_response response) {
        << get result, parse it and return the **values** >>
    });

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    GetXMLAsync().wait();
    use the **values** in the rest of the code
}
```

Appreciate any insight on this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
pptx::task<http_response> test() {}

auto request_task = test();
auto response = request_task.get();
```

Then you can use the response variable as you need.  Hoping that this helps others.